# I catch the exception but still see it thrown in the logs

Tags: java, jpa, exception

I have an application in Weblogic using JPA. Sometimes when I merge objects to DB I get a SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException. I catch that exception and handle it. The issue is I am still seeing the exception in the logs even though it's caught and handled. Some code:

```
public class MyClass implements MessageListener {
 public void onMessage(Message message) {
    //do stuff
    SomeItem someItem = processItem(request);
    localEJB.mergeAnotherItem(someItem);

}
private SomeItem processItem(ItemType item) throws Exception {            
        int retry = 0;
            boolean success = false;
            while ((!success) && (retry <= 3)) {
                try {

                    Item dbItem =  myEJB.mergeItem(item); //this causes exception
                    item = dbItem;
                    success = true;
                } catch (TransactionRolledbackLocalException ex) {
                    retry++;
                    if (ex.getCause().toString().contains("SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException")) {
                    logger.log("TransactionRolledbackLocalException SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException while merging on try # " + retry);
                        Item dbItem2 = myEJB.findItem(itemName);
                        if dbItem2 != null) {
                            item= dbItem2 ;
                        }
                        if (retry > 3) {
                            //log
                        }
                    } 
                }catch(Exception ex){
                        //log cause, etc
                    }
    }   

}
```

My EJB code that I'm calling the methods from

```
@Stateless(name = "MyEJB", mappedName = "MyService-MySessionEJB")
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class MyEJBBean implements MyEJBSessionEJB,
                                                        MySessionEJBLocal {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MyModel")
    private EntityManager em;


    public Item mergeItem(Item item) {
        return em.merge(item); //This throws the SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException, an internal exception wrapped in TransactionRolledbackLocalException. Which I'm catching in the caller
    }


     /** <code>select o from Items o where o.itemName = :itemName</code> */
         public Item findItem(String itemName) {
             try {
                 return (Item)em.createNamedQuery("Item.findByName").setParameter("itemName", itemName).getSingleResult();
             } catch (NoResultException e) {
                 return null;
             }
         }


}
```

In the logs I see that the mergeItem sometimes fails. Then it retries it. It works after the first retry. But in the logs I see three entries when it fails

A warning:

```
    UnitOfWork(738260825)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ITEM1_UK) violated
```

An error:

```
    Exception occurred during commit of transaction Name=[EJB MyEJB.mergeItem(Item)],Xid=BEA1-29FF28139113B72A3D9D(738260452),Status=Rolled back. [Reason=Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (ITEM1_UK) violated
```

And then my log entry when I catch the exception

```
TransactionRolledbackLocalException SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException while merging on try # 1
```

I'm clearly catching the exception but at the same time I still see the exception in the logs.
I tries catching Exception e but it never catches that...the exception is the transaction one.

If the Exception is being caught why do I still see it in the logs?

Comment: Some debugging should clarify things

Comment: debug and other logging settings are what are causing the JPA provider and container to log the messages before throwing them to your application.  That way you can know about it despite having possibly incorrect error handling that swallows exceptions without notifying you.

Comment: @Chris Thank you. That actually answers the question of "why is exception still being thrown"

Answer (score 2):

EclipseLink has special property `eclipselink.logging.exceptions` for logging exceptions

> Use eclipselink.logging.exceptions to specify if exceptions are logged when the are thrown, before returning the exception to the calling application. - See more at: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_logging_exceptions.htm

And it's default value is true. So you just need to set property value to false.

For example in persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="false" />
```

**UPDATE**

It turned out that EclipseLink documentation gives confusing description of `eclipselink.logging.exceptions` property.

The property value is set to `shouldLogExceptionStackTrace` logger flag

```
String exString = getConfigPropertyAsStringLogDebug(PersistenceUnitProperties.LOGGING_EXCEPTIONS, m, session);
if (exString != null) {
    log.setShouldLogExceptionStackTrace(Boolean.parseBoolean(exString));
}
```

Name of `shouldLogExceptionStackTrace` flag says that it is about logging stacktrace but not about exception itself. It is used in following way:

```
if (shouldLogExceptionStackTrace()) {
    entry.getException().printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(getWriter()));
} else {
    writeMessage(entry.getException().toString());
}
```

I've checked other logging parameters and looks like the only way to remove EclipseLink exceptions from the log is to use appropriate logging level or disable logging

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="OFF"/>
```

See more details on EclipsLink wiki [How To Configure Logging](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging#How_To_Configure_Logging)

Comment: Great insight. However, this particularly didn't stop the logging of the exception.

Comment: @jr-dev You are right. Documentation gives wrong description. I've updated answer